# Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a + gettype(fn))

Tags: node.js, express

when i try to run a app.js file i got this error.

```
 throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn))
  ^
TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a string
```

Here is my app.js file

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.use("views engine", "ejs");

app.get("/", function(req, res){
  res.render("home");
});
app.get("/fellinlovewith/:thing", function(req, res){
  var animal = req.param.thing;
  res.render("love", {thing:animal});
});
app.get("/posts", function(req, res){
  var posts = [
      {book1:"author1"},
      {book2:"author2"},
      {book3:"author3"},
      {book4:"author4"}
      ];
  res.render("post", {posts:posts});
});

app.listen(1250,function() {
  console.log("server started listining!!!");
});
```

As i'm new to this stuff i don't have any idea what are routes and middleware stuff. when i run the app.js file with nodemon i got this same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `app.set()`, not `app.use()` so change:

```
app.use("views engine", "ejs");
```

to:

```
app.set("views engine", "ejs");
```